# Angular Factory returning index.html as response.data instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm lost on this one.

I've set up a productFactory that is meant to `$http.get` hardcoded JSON data. This JSON has been validated by JSONlint.

Instead of returning this data, the data returned is my index.html file. What could be causing this?

productFactory:

```
angular.module('APP').factory('productFactory', function($http) {
    var productFactory = {
        getProducts:function(){
            return $http.get('/public/data/product.json')
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response;
                });
        },
    }
    return productFactory;
})
```

The response logged to the console is a string version of my entire index.html file.

Comment: My project on github has good example of this. Check out the services and conteollers here https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000/tree/master/CordovaApp/CordovaApp/js

Comment: `What could be causing this` ... server routing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `/public/` actually a part of the path to the file? Usually the public folder is set up as the document root and doesn't actually appear in the path to any resource.

Try getting to view `product.json` in a browser and make sure Angular is calling `GET` on the same path.

Comment: Yup, I completely overlooked that. It was my path. Thank you for being extra eyes!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this  ?

```
angular.fromJson(response);
```